# No ca.pem file found when running a docker agent

Tags: docker, ssl, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Pipeline execution failed when using a docker agent due to missing ca.pem file.

**Jenkins Setup**

```
Jenkins: 2.426.3
OS: Linux - 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Java: 17.0.9 - Eclipse Adoptium (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
```

---

I started jenkins service using this docker compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  jenkins-blueocean:
    image: myjenkins-blueocean:1
    container_name: jenkins-blueocean
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - jenkins
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376
      - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client
      - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"

networks:
  jenkins:

volumes:
  jenkins-data:
  jenkins-docker-certs:
```

I am trying to execute a pipeline using a docker agent like so:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:20-alpine'
            args '-p 3000:3000'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building...'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem arises as soon as it executes this line:

```
+ docker inspect -f . node:20-alpine
```

Which causes the following error:

```
Failed to initialize: unable to resolve docker endpoint: open /certs/client/ca.pem: no such file or directory
```

Where do I find this `ca.pem` file and how do I configure `Jenkins` to use it?